# why my main controller is not found to codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

hi i have problem with `namespace` in `codeIgniter`.

what i'm trying to do is:

1. i have downloaded `phpmailer` with `composer`
2. it has 2 `namespaces`   they are

> use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
>
> use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

whenerver i include this `namespace` it will give this `error`

> Class 'Frontend_Controller' not found

here is my controller code :

**No Error Code - this code works fine**

```
class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller {
   //my code goes here
}
```

**This code gives Error**

```
 require "vendor/autoload.php";

 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class Welcome extends Frontend_Controller {
   // my code goes here....
}
```

i have tried this link but giving same error : https://gist.github.com/JeyKeu/7533af3b9b5fd078910d  if i put the code in `application\config\config.php`

please help me thanks in advance

Comment: use statement should come inside the class...inside constructor function you have to mention that use statement...

Comment: @Mahesh, i have tried but it is giving same `error`

Comment: @Mahesh, the actual problem is with `require` this line ` require `"vendor/autoload.php"`;
`

Comment: now what you want exactly..you have use SMTP mail function..right?

Comment: my `mail` functionality is working fine with `core php` i have tested

Comment: now the problem is with this line `require "vendor/autoload.php"`

Comment: yes...but in codeigniter these things no need...

Comment: then how can i do it? please help me

Comment: i have added the sample code for email sending using php mailer..its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

inside config folder create a file email.php...

```
<?php
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; 
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'youraccount@gmail.com'; 
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'test@12#'; 
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
?>
```

and in main controller...

```
    $params['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $params['subject'] = ' Something ';
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from('info@test.co.in', 'Application name');
    $this->email->to('example@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject($params['subject']);
    $this->email->message($this->load->view('your_view_page', $params, true));
    $this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter 2.x

add the below line in index.php

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
```

and now inside the controller

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

for more info Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15244577/7296317

CodeIgniter 3.x

If you want `CodeIgniter` to use a `Composer auto-loader`, just set `$config['composer_autoload']` to `TRUE` or a custom path in `application/config/config.php.`

REF : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html

and also at the top of your file where you want to use PHP mailer, probably need something like:

```
use PHPMailer;
```