# Codeigniter 3 composer and vendor directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-amqplib

I have installed codeigniter 3.1.8 and installed this library https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib using composer:

`composer require php-amqplib/php-amqplib`

This has created a directory vendor [image]

I have looked the accepted answer on how to use the library here [How to use composer packages in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741917/how-to-use-composer-packages-in-codeigniter?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

but this is my directory structure in vendor.

[image]

second

and inside php-amqplib

[image]

and inside php-amqplib

[image]

If i look at `index.php` i find that fcpath has already been defined

```
// Path to the front controller (this file) directory
define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

and defining it again will result in an error.How can i get to use php-amqplib inside my controller methods?.

Comment: have you tried :  require_once APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Nope, but i can do that. In that answer, i have to put vendor iside application. Does it mean the application folder that codeigniter creates or should it remain where it is in my screenshot and how can i now access it in my controller?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### IF your question is - How can i get to use php-amqplib inside my controller methods ?

STEP - 1 :

Allow or require the autoload.php file on very beginning, but on codeigniter you cannot do that in general.So change one line on config file that will automatically require `autoload.php` file.

`CodeIgniter/application/config/config.php` find :

`$config['composer_autoload'] = FALSE;` to `$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;`

STEP - 2 :

On your controller class like this :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
   public function index()
   {
        // your business logic like this
        $msg = new AMQPMessage($msg_body);
        $ch->batch_basic_publish($msg, $exchange);
   }
}
```

STEP - 3 :

Now you can call it via URL

```
http://example.com/Welcome
```

Now more `ref:` [PhpAmqpLib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib)

Comment: vendor must be in the codeigniter application directory.

Comment: How can i close the connection at the end of the controller function?.

Comment: @Gandalf If you have additional questions, please post them separately - this site is designed to have one question and its answers on each page, rather than threads of discussion, so that it's easier for future readers to find the answer they need.

Answer (score 1):

Change composer_autoload config in /application/config/config.php like below 
`$config['composer_autoload'] = 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 0):

This will open and close the connection

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection; 

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
        $channel = $connection->channel();
        $channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

        $msg = new AMQPMessage('Yur message goes here....');
        $channel->basic_publish($msg, '', 'hello');

        $channel->close();
        $connection->close();

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```