# Export & download html to pdf in codeigniter 3 using mPDF erro:Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I am trying to export and download the html view incidentView.php to pdf by pressing print button in incidentView.php, using mPDF.I am able to convert to pdf now even though the loading is very slow,but now I am getting error regarding the data that I am trying to get on pdf.Basically I can not convert the Dynamic data can you please help me how I should get them?

I have download mPDF by using:

> composer require mpdf/mpdf

config.php

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Incident.php Controller

```
function get_pdf_test($id)
  {
    $data['incidents'] = $this->incidents_model->getByIdPdf($id);
    $data['incidents_history'] = $this->incidents_model->getById_historyPdf($id); 
    $data['company_name'] = $this->incidents_model->getAllCompanyNamePdf();
    require_once (APPPATH. 'vendor/autoload.php');
    $path = '/tmp/mpdf'; 
     if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
     }
     $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => $path]);
     $html = $this->load->view('admin/incidents/incidentsPdf',[],true);
     $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
     $mpdf->Output(); 
     $mpdf->Output('incidentsPdf.pdf','D'); 

}
```

incidentPdf.php view

```
<div class="TaskView" > 
    <h2 class="heading" ><?php echo "ASGB_IN".str_pad($incidents->incidents_id, '4', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);?></h2>
      <!-- <form action="<?php echo base_url('get_pdf_test/'.$incidents->id);?>" method="post" >       -->
    <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="email">Incidents ID</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="T_id" placeholder="Name" name="T_id" value="<?php echo "ASGB_IN".str_pad($incidents->incidents_id, '4', '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);?>" readonly>
            </div>
           <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="email">Incidents Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tname" placeholder="Name" name="Tname" value="<?php echo $incidents->incident_name;?>" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="pwd">Company Name</label>
              <input  type="text"class="form-control" id="Cname" name="Cname" value="<?php echo $incidents->company_name;?>"readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="pwd">Project Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Pname" name="Pname" value="<?php echo $incidents->project_name;?>" readonly>
            </div>
```

incident_model.php

```
 function getById_history_pdf($id)
{
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT incidents_id FROM incidents WHERE id = $id");
    $get_row = $query->row();
    $incident_id = $get_row->incidents_id;
    
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where(array('incidents.incidents_id'=>$incident_id));
    $this->db->join('incident_status', 'incidents.id = incident_status.incident_id');
    return $this->db->get('incidents')->result_array(); 
} 


function getAllCompanyNamePdf()
{
  $query = $this->db->get('company_details');
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT company_name FROM company_details where delete_flag =0');
  return $query->result_array();
}

function getByIdPdf($id) 
{
   return $this->db->get_where('incidents',array('id'=>$id))->row_array();
}
```

vendor location

[image]

pdf
[image]

Comment: you store the MPDF Libraray?

Comment: Do I need to do that? since i have installed mPDF by using  :   composer require mpdf/mpdf

Comment: Include file (Mpdf\Mpdf) first before using it on your controller

Comment: @ Aman Tiwari I have added :  require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';    in my controller and now getting this error : require_once(/opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Not sure why you have included vendor autoload like that, since CI4 had composer library discovery enabled already for each vendor.

Comment: so can you advise what I need to do ?

Comment: @AmanTiwari Can you please advise how to include it?

Comment: Where is your `vendor` folder located? inside `admin` folder or inside `application` folder? It looks like you are using wrong folder. If you can provide a clear structure, I can tell you the correct path to use.

Comment: @DhavalChheda I have added image which shows the location

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

inside your controller file. `__DIR__` evaluates to the directory of the file that used it. Since this is a controller file, you are trying to load

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin/vendor/autoload.php
```

as `__DIR__` evaluated to `/opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/controllers/admin` which is not the correct path.

A correct code would be

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
```

A better solution is to use `APPPATH` so you wouldn't have to know the relative path.

```php
require_once APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';
```

You can also

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = true;
```

You can find more info [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741917/how-to-use-composer-packages-in-codeigniter)

Lastly, in the GitHb readme.md you can see this.

> It is recommended to set one's own temporary directory via tempDir configuration variable. The directory must have write permissions (mode 775 is recommended) for users using mPDF (typically cli, webserver, fpm).

This means that you need a writable folder for temporary operations. You can initialize the temp location to any place you prefer using

```php
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '/tmp']);
```

`/tmp` is always writable. However, you can make any folder and path the path for it as a parameter like

```php
$path = '/tmp/mpdf'; // You should change this as prefered.
if (!file_exists($path)) {
    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
}
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => $path]);
```

Comment: Amm it seems that this is a complete clone of Vickel's answer... it would be nice if you had another solution, but a exact copy of an older answer wouldn't be so nice...

Comment: @U11-Forward Vickel's answer didn't go through why issue and went straight into a proposed solution. I tried to cover the reason of the issue and how to solve it. Also if you check the chat, his problem wasn't over.

Comment: Also why did you edit a triple quote block with space padded block? You only did that in the first one and frankly I see no difference, so if I am missing something, it would be great to let me understand.

Comment: I have used : require_once APPPATH.'vendor/autoload.php';    and now getting error :Temporary files directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable

Comment: I have tried to make the file writable in FTP but can not find this specific file

Comment: @RoxanaSlj you need to make a folder writable.
You can use the the last code segment to create a writable one. Just change the `$path` variable to any path that you prefer.

Comment: yes already did that , I have edit the question please have a look

Comment: @RoxanaSlj the last error is logical error, you try to access `$incidents->incidents_id` in your view but you used `->result_array();` which returns array and not object.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your composer/manual mpdf installation is located in the directory

```
application\vendor
```

set in your config\config.php

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = true;
```

or use in your controller:

```
require_once (APPPATH. 'vendor/autoload.php');
```

Depending on the version of mpdf installed, you can use namespaces (V.7+) like:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

Other versions (V.6.x) use:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
```

so just change your function like this:

```
function DownloadPdf()
{
    //require_once (APPPATH. 'vendor/autoload.php'); //-> you don't need this line if set in config.php
    $mpdf = new mPDF();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
    $mpdf->Output();    
}
```

[issue documented](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/226)

Comment: I have already tried that, it is not working

Comment: So what is the issue?

Comment: put vendor inside the application folder

Comment: did you remove the line `require once` ?

Comment: yes by removing that i get error: Class 'Mpdf\Mpdf' not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227452/discussion-between-vickel-and-roxana-slj).

Comment: or eroor:Class 'mPDF' not found

Answer (score 0):

Just run `composer dump-autoload` in order to update the auto-loader... then `\Mpdf\Mpdf` should become known. If that shouldn't work out, check & fix the file-systems permissions and try again (while `vendor/autoload.php` cannot be written, it obviously cannot add it into the auto-loader).

For XAMPP on Linux, ownership should likely be (there's no `777` required, nor recommended):

```
chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs
```

And by adding another user into group `daemon`, they'll share the group's permissions.

Comment: error:Temporary files directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/ticketing_tool_v2/application/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable

how can I make it writable ? I have used 777 in ftp but still same

Comment: Use SSH2 instead of FTP (with a user that is allowed to write there). `chmod 777` is always a bad idea; rather `chown -R user:group /opt/lampp/htdocs`. On Linux, using such LAMPP distribution is also kind of pretty useless, because one can install all of that with the package-manager; out-of-the-box. But based upon the error message, one can assume that my guess was correct.

Comment: If you're able to run `composer dump-autoload` offline and then upload the resulting files via FTP, it also may work out. I'm not exactly certain, since I do not use any LAMPP ...but I think user & group are called `daemon` there (the config file should provide certainty).

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, the Issue doesn't seem to be the mPDF, it seems to be the data.
Error 1: You have undefined incidents, this is causing the issue to create the PDF.

Error 2: You are passing an Object, however, mPDF requires you to pass an Array. You will need to convert the Model Return data using asArray or simply using return type of array for the model.

Reference: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html

Also, you don't need to explicitly define the autoload in your controller.
Another thing to notice from the screenshot is it is creating the PDF, however, because the errors are throw, you can't see the PDF properly.

UPDATE: Potential Issue maybe that data is not passed to the View at all. Following code must be passing empty data

```
 $html = $this->load->view('admin/incidents/incidentsPdf',[],true);
```

Here [] is passing the empty data, so the View may not be receiving any data even though it is set in the controller.

Comment: I have added my model as well , please have a look.

Comment: yes the problem here is I can't get dynamic data

Comment: print_r($data);
      die;   : IS returning data correctly but in conversion it doesnt

Comment: @RoxanaSlj I have updated my Answer. Have a look at it.

Comment: I have changed to this : $html = $this->load->view('admin/incidents/incidentsPdf', $data,true);

Comment: also tried : $html = $this->load->view('admin/incidents/incidentsPdf', [$data],true);   but getting same error

Comment: Just pass $data not [$data]. @RoxanaSlj

Comment: What I would suggest you is first try with small static data rather than dynamic data. Then one by one you can improve on that. Because issue is definitely with data mPDF is fine.